# Adding a User Rep/Question Threshold ala Slashdot?

Tags: feature-request

Would like to see the ability to hide the questions that are visible to *me* if a question is asked by a user with a reputation lower than a threshold set in personal preferences.

EDIT

I meant as a personal preference, to be able to hide which questions *I see*.  This is similar to how Slashdot does it: you can hide comments that are below a certain threshold, but this in no way impacts what *others* see.  Obviously by default this would be disabled.

Why?  To see more meaningful, rewarding questions to answer in the first few pages; to eliminate some "noise" if you will.

EDIT2

This feature was proposed for the wrong reasons, when I should've "counted to 10" if you will, and proof that correlation does not imply causation.  As a few of you pointed out correctly, just because a lot of 1st-time questions are abandoned by their author, it doesn't mean that *all* 1st-time questions are a waste of time; it's up to you to decide whether or not you want to spend time answering a question or not, and that takes more than just the user rep to decide.

Comment: Why would you like to see this ?

Comment: To see more questions from users with greater rep.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: See latest edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you seriously suggesting that good questions only come from those with greater than some arbitrary rep? What about answers? Do good answers also only come from those with X rep?

I can only assume you look at the rep, not the question, and in doing so have missed many of the best questions on SF. What about your own questions - were those you posted early on really bad and te later ones fantastic? I suspect the rep you possessed at the time had no bearing on the quality of the questions.

To do what you propose, even as an individual user setting, would be most unfair to those with low rep and I would remind you that we all started out as low rep members ourselves.

Comment: Golden example.... +1

Comment: see latest edit.  You're right; bad idea.

Answer (score 9):

**Absolutely not!**

The majority of our traffic is from Google, and in probably 95% of cases that means an unregistered (and thus one rep) user. Server Fault is here to share good information with the masses, and hiding questions to users with a reputation less than `$threshold` will totally alienate the majority of our users.

If you're thinking of this as some way to prevent loads of "I have this problem too" or "thanks" answers, then locked and protected posts goes some way towards preventing it - moderator flags should catch the remainder.

Comment: +1 deserves more....

Comment: You misunderstood what I was asking; see revised question.

Comment: Ben there is the protect question permission to do exactly that :)

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with this, just because I have a low rep doesn't mean I can't ask a great and / or a useful question. That just denies low rep users to getting their question seen. Just because a person hasn't gained a lot of rep doesn't mean that they don't know what they're doing, there just new.... I only have 500 rep does this mean my question isn't worthy; furthermore how am I supposed to get better/ gain more rep if no one ever looks at my question.

EDIT

To borrow what Robert Moir said what if Linus Torvalds joins today; he asks a question.... he's qualified to be here but he has the same starting rep as everyone else

Comment: Linus is a sysadmin now? I always thought his knowledge would be more on-topic over at SO... :)

Comment: I quoted Robert Moir.... Take it up with him:)... He has to be somewhat of an admin I'd assume though.

Comment: That's why he has to ask HOW to use Linux here. It's only on SO where he gets to tell people how it works internally ;-)

Comment: I'd think they guy that wrote the kernel would be highly skilled with using the OS?